# How do I insert multiple points in Influx with the lineprotocol and API

Tags: influxdb, influx-line-protocol

According to the [documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.1/reference/syntax/line-protocol/) the influx line protocol accepts **\n** to separate lines.

I have a request in Postman on Windows *http://127.0.0.1:8086/api/v2/write?precision=ms&bucket=Test&org=Test* with required headers
that works just fine with this line in the Body:

- tag,id=87 value=17855 1636735893871

So I would naturally expect something like this to work for multiple points:

- tag,id=87 value=17855 1636735893871 \n tag,id=87 value=17856 1636736594952
- tag,id=87 value=17855 1636735893871\ntag,id=87 value=17856 1636736594952
- tag,id=87 value=17855 1636735893871 \ntag,id=87 value=17856 1636736594952
- tag,id=87 value=17855 1636735893871\n tag,id=87 value=17856 1636736594952

Unnecessary to say I tried this as well:

- tag,id=87 value=17855 1636735893871
  tag,id=87 value=17856 1636736594952

I am recieving either a "bad timestamp" or "point is invalid" error in the response

Even tried forward slashes just for sport. Any clues on how to insert more than one point?

Thank you.

Comment: Opened issue on github : https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/22874

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this boils down to the Windows vs Unix End Of Line implementation.

Postman, NotePad++, Devtools, VS whatever editor running on windows, will write a lineshift as \r\n, (hex 0D 0A) that currently is not supported by the influx lineprotocol although it seems like a trivial implementation (skip 0D).

As for my own problem coding in C# adding a (char)10 between points solved the problem instead of using Environment.NewLine.

Cheers!